# How to make Application.key Shortcuts WorkBook Specific?

Tags: excel, vba

I added code to a series of similar files for different projects.

I defined a (Control + R)  "`^ + R`" shortcut to let users see the current record in a userform.

I added `application.key` code on workbook activating and deactivating event, so the shortcut can be used when several files of this type are open.

My problem is even if the form opens and reads the data from the respective workbook, the userform is not called from the respective file!

Should I localize the procedure as well?

Here are my codes:

## The Code in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    With Application
        .OnKey "^R", "ReadCurrentRecord"
    
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.OnKey "^R"
End Sub
```

## The Code in a general Module

```
Sub ReadCurrentRecord()
    If ActiveCell.Worksheet.Name = "OSW" Then
        If OSWRng Is Nothing Then
            Set OSW = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OSW")
            Set OSWRng = OSW.Range("a5:bz2000")
        End If
        
        FrmWODetails.Tag = OSW.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14)
        FrmWODetails.UserForm_Activate
        FrmWODetails.Show vbModeless
    End If
End Sub
```

All the Names are same in the files.

Answer (score 1):

thisworkbook and activecell may not be what you expect them to be.

if this is an addin, this workbook will refer to the addin while active cell wont.  i don't even know if activate a cell can be used in an add-in' sheet... I'm thinking not, I'll test that then i get to s computer for my own knowledge.

it's almost always best to fully qualify the object, sometimes from the application level but normally the workbook will suffice

personally, I prefer codenames over names and babes over indexes but they have a few drawbacks that keep them from being my#1 choice

Comment: Hello, 
No, it is not an Add-On, that why I think using **thisworkbook** is very safe. Anyway, I found a workaround and not have such a problem anymore. Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem.  Would you mind posting the work around so we can all learn from your experience?

Comment: I have noticed 1) I have to add the .onkey command on the *WorkBook_open* event as well, otherwise the keys will not assign to the workbook, which was strange for me. 2) On my forms, I added a activate command on Combobox which I was using for selecting the target workbook. So it was not actually very genuine. ;-)